# FirstBaseline of NSLayoutAttribute, what does it mean?

Tags: swift

The following is the swift version of enum NSLayoutAttribute. However I couldn't find any explanation about FirstBaseline. Thx!

```
enum NSLayoutAttribute : Int {
    case Left
    case Right
    case Top
    case Bottom
    case Leading
    case Trailing
    case Width
    case Height
    case CenterX
    case CenterY
    case Baseline
    case FirstBaseline
    case NotAnAttribute
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mentioned in some of the WWDC sessions (what's new in table and collection views, I think). There are now two baseline attributes for multiline labels, so you can pin to the first and last lines.

Comment: Why isn't there something like LastBaseline?

Comment: It seems to me that BaseLine also means "LastBaseline" in case of mulit-line UILabel.